# LTV enabling signatures in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

As I understand there are two ways doing this by

- adding DSS dictionary
- embedding CRLs or OCSP responses in the signature at signing time

The DSS way seems to work and Adobe recognizes the signature as LTV enabled. The second way would fit much more into our application so I still try to get it to work. I'm having issues adding the OCSP responses to the signature so I only try to add the certificates and the CRLs. Correct me if I'm wrong but as I understand, either the CRLs or the OCSP responses should be added to the signature. There is no need for both? I collect the signing certificate and its root certificate, also the TSA certificate and its root certificate. After that, I fetch all the CRLs. All this is added before the signing and the timestamp. Adding only the certificates and the CRLs doesn't seem to work because Adobe doesn't recognize the signature as LTV enabled. I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong so any help is appreciated!

```
Store crlStore = new JcaCRLStore(crls); 
gen.addCRLs(crlStore);

Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(certList); 
gen.addCertificates(certStore);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is putting the CRLs into the CMS signature container element generally used for CRLs. In case of integrated PDF signatures, though, the situation is different; here CRLs are expected in a special signed attribute instead.

Have a look at ISO 32000-1 where this attribute already is specified:

> The PKCS#7 object should contain the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Revocation information as an signed attribute (PDF 1.6): This attribute may include all the revocation information that is necessary to carry out revocation checks for the signer's certificate and its issuer certificates. Since revocation information is a signed attribute, it must be obtained before the computation of the digital signature. This means that the software used by the signer must be able to construct the certification path and the associated revocation information. If one of the elements cannot be obtained (e.g. no connection is possible), a signature with this attribute will not be possible.
>
> ...
>
> #### 12.8.3.3.2 Revocation Information
>
> The adbe Revocation Information attribute:
>
> ```
> adbe-revocationInfoArchival OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
>                               { adbe(1.2.840.113583) acrobat(1) security(1) 8 }
> ```
>
> The value of the revocation information attribute can include any of the following data types:
>
> - Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs), described in RFC 3280 (see the Bibliography): CRLs are generally large and therefore should not be embedded in the PKCS#7 object.
> - Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) Responses, described in RFC 2560, *X.509 Internet Public Key Infrastructure Online Certificate Status Protocol — OCSP* (see the Bibliography): These are generally small and constant in size and should be the data type included in the PKCS#7 object.
> - Custom revocation information: The format is not prescribed by this specification, other than that it be encoded as an OCTET STRING. The application should be able to determine the type of data contained within the OCTET STRING by looking at the associated OBJECT IDENTIFIER.
>
> adbe's Revocation Information attribute value has ASN.1 type RevocationInfoArchival:
>
> ```
> RevocationInfoArchival ::= SEQUENCE {
>   crl [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE of CRLs, OPTIONAL
>   ocsp [1] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE of OCSP Responses, OPTIONAL
>   otherRevInfo [2] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE of OtherRevInfo, OPTIONAL
> }
> OtherRevInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
>   Type OBJECT IDENTIFIER
>   Value OCTET STRING
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I came to the same conclusion after reading some documentations and questions here. One question particularly answered by you. :) I'm adding the CRLs and the OCSP responses now and Adobe recognizes the signature as LTV enabled. It takes too much time though to collect all this information.

Comment: *"It takes too much time though to collect all this information."* - Well, depending on your use case some caching may help. If you embed CRLs, you can usually re-use them for quite a while as they are re-published not that often. The situation is a bit different with OCSP responses which are expected to be quite fresh, but for a few minutes they often can be cached, too. On the other hand, if signing with the same certificates (or only a few of them) and adding revocation information afterwards, i.e. in a DSS, you can  conserve even more time, adding information in batches.

Comment: Thanks! I think embedding them in the signature fits more right now. I will try some caching.

Comment: We were creating some signatures right after we were discussing LTV here so around 3 months ago. Back then and also after Adobe said that the signature is LTV enabled. I checked the documents yesterday and Adobe says now: Signature is not LTV enabled and will expire after 2022/05/22... We only added the OCSP responses to the signature. What can the problem be? Is there a way to check your newly signed documents to avoid this? Should I ask a question instead?

Comment: Please share the pdf in question. Maybe you added not all the information needed. Unfortunately Adobe does not publish their exact validation requirements, so their "LTV- enabled" can be a moving target.

Comment: Not sure if I can share the file. Interesting though that the signatures in PDFs that have been created at the same time but also contain the CRLs are still LTV enabled.

Comment: You say you have included OCSP responses. Have you also checked the OCSP signer certificates? They may also need revocation information... And even if they have an id-pkix-ocsp-nocheck attribute, this strictly speaking only helps for the time of the OCSP signer certificate.

Comment: Yes, I guess OCSP signer certificates are missing.

Comment: One has to wonder, though, why the file originally was shown as LTV enabled and is not anymore. Have you had any Adobe Acrobat updates in the meantime? Or has the CA that issues your certificate been compromised or otherwise decommissioned?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. How can one be sure this won't happen after one week or so. Difficult to say but I guess I have had updated since June. I just updated Adobe today to the latest but it still says the same. I will check the CA but I don't think so. It's a certificate from Sectigo.